# How to get capture groups in a regular expression match used for replace

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have the following program that demonstrates replacing matches found in a regular expression search:

```
using System;

public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
        var regexSearch = @"\{(\w+)\}";
        var format = "{Level}:{Name}:{Message}";
        var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regexSearch);
        var result = regex.Replace(format, Test.Replace);
        Console.WriteLine($"result = {result}");
    }

    public static string Replace(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match) {
        Console.WriteLine($"match = {match}");
        return "<replacement>";
    }
}
```

This prints the following to standard out:

```
match = {Level}
match = {Name}
match = {Message}
result = <replacement>:<replacement>:<replacement>
```

How would I get the code to print the following instead if only the `Replace` method may be changed?

```
match = Level
match = Name
match = Message
result = Level:Name:Message
```

I am aware of `Match.Groups` and `Match.Captures` but keep finding strings that include the curly braces.

---

The following example is an even better illustration of my true goal:

```
using System;

public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
        var regexSearch = @"\{(\w+)\}";
        var format = "{Level}:{Name}:{Message}";
        var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regexSearch);
        var record = new Information(Importance.Normal, "John Doe", "Hello, world!");
        var result = regex.Replace(format, x => Test.Replace(x, record));
        Console.WriteLine($"result = {result}");
    }

    public static string Replace(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match, Information record) {
        Console.WriteLine($"match = {match}");
        var name = "Level";
        var property = record.GetType().GetProperty(name);
        if (property == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{name} is not available");
        }
        var value = property.GetValue(record);
        if (value is DateTime) {
            return ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
        }
        return value.ToString();
    }
}

public class Information {
    public Importance Level { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Message { get; }
    public DateTime Created { get; }

    public Information(Importance level, string name, string message) {
        this.Level = level;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Message = message;
        this.Created = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public enum Importance {
    Low,
    Normal,
    Hight
}
```

The program works almost exactly as expected but writes this to standard output:

```
match = {Level}
match = {Name}
match = {Message}
result = Normal:Normal:Normal
```

Line 15 of the program says `var name = "Level";` and needs to get the name in the capture group of the match. The output should say this instead:

```
match = {Level}
match = {Name}
match = {Message}
result = Normal:John Doe:Hello, world!
```

Does anyone know how to get the contents of the regular expression capture group so line 15 can be replaced with the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that your expectation of `Groups` is incorrect. It does not only contains each capture group but also the entire match. Its length should be one more than expected, and the first group should be at index one.

---

In your 1st example, change line 14 so that it reads:

```
return match.Groups[1].Value;
```

---

In your 2nd example, change line 15 so that it reads:

```
var name = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the following code within your Replace method, it is only ever looking for name -> "Level".

If you go into debug mode, put a breakpoint in your Replace method and f11 through it... You'll see that every 'cycle' of the method, the property will always be "Level"

You could do several things to solve this... such as including a counter that increases by one every time the method is called... followed by a switch statement to determine what name should be equal to... among other things.

Comment: The explanation is in relation to the example you provided.